# cannot get data by id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get detailed data about a user by their id but when I try, I get an error: `undefined variable`.

controller

```
function index()
    {       

        $this->data['prodi'] = $this->mprodi->get_prodi();

        $id_anggota = $this->uri->segment(3);


        $this->load->model('mdaftar');
        $this->data['anggota'] = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar();
        $this->data['detail'] = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($id_anggota);

        dump($this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($id_anggota));
        echo '<pre>'. $this->db->last_query() . '</pre>' ;


        $this->data['title'] ='UKM Taekwondo';
        $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('anggota/profil', $this->data, true);
        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/anggota/wrapper_ukt',$this->data);

    }
```

model

```
function get_daftar_detail($id_anggota)
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('mahasiswa');
        $this->db->join('pendaftaran_anggota','pendaftaran_anggota.nim = mahasiswa.nim','left');
        $this->db->where('id_anggota',$id_anggota);
        $this->db->join('prodi','prodi.id_prodi = mahasiswa.id_prodi','left');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->row();
    }
```

and this is the view

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('anggota/profil/'.$id_anggota); ?>">

        <div class="ui instagram button widget-body">
            Kelola Profil
        </div>
 </a>
```

error is `undefined variable id_anggota` in the view. Please help me with what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you will get error because you didn't passed that id in controller ,

```
$this->data['yourid'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

And use this id to your view.

Comment: i try but error undifined id_anggota in $this->data['detail'] = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($id_anggota); and i change with $this->data['detail'] = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($this->data['id_anggota']);

Comment: but it always error. i vardump  $this->data['detail'] but id is null

Comment: I see,make sure uri segment is proper. I mean it gives value.

Comment: i think uri segment is always true my link is http://localhost/tkd/index.php/anggota/profil/detail_anggota and my uri segment $this->uri->segment(4);

Comment: how? when i try var dupm uri segment is false

Comment: $this->uri->segment (3) would return proper value

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your controller

```
$data['id_anggota'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
```